# C++ string swap character places

Tags: c++, string, swap

is there a way to swap character places in a string? For example if I have `"03/02"` I need to get `"02/03"`.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: If your question is deeper than the two answers, then you need to expand on it to tell us what you're really asking?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Sure:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string s = "03/02";
std::swap(s[1], s[4]);
```

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think you'd benefit from move semantics in this case?

Comment: Why would using move on the arguments be more general?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You're right, the interna of swap are unaffected. Let me remove those comments then. Perhaps an rvalue overload could let you swap with a temporary, but that's not relevant to this situation. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::swap(str[1], str[4]);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is. :)

`std::swap(str[i], str[j])`

Answer (score 0):

Wait, do you really want such a specific answer? You don't care about if the string is 2/3 instead of 02/03?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

bool ReverseString(const char *input)
{
    const char *index = strchr(input, (int) '/');
    if(index == NULL)
        return false;

    char *result = new char[strlen(input) + 1];

    strcpy(result, index + 1);
    strcat(result, "/");
    strncat(result, input, index - input);

    printf("%s\r\n", result);
    delete [] result;

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *test = "03/02";
    ReverseString(test);
}
```

Comment: but it did answer my question and now I know how to solve the whole exercise :D